# login wont work in mozilla firefox, but works in safari, chrome and ie?

Tags: php, authentication

im having a problem with my login script in mozilla firefox, for some reason it wont let a user log in. my login script works fine in ie chrome and safari.

Here's my code, i wonder why its not letting people login, any ideas please?

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" form action="login.php" method="post" class="loginform">

Email
  <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="30" />

Password
<input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" />

<input type="image" src="../PTB1/assets/img/icons/loginarrow1.png" name="submit" class="loginbutton" value="Login" />

            </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    if (logged_in()) 

{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\"></div><div class=\"login-box\"><div class=\"loginframe2\">
<h1>Login You In Securely </h1>
<p>login you in securely. Please wait.<br/><br/>
<div class=\"login-logo\">
  <img src=\"assets/css/photobox/loading.gif\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"><div class=\"login-text-logo\">Login You In. Please Wait</div></div>
</div></div>"; 
header("Location:home.php");


}

    include_once("includes/form_functions.php");


    // START FORM PROCESSING
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { // Form has been submitted.
        $errors = array();

        // perform validations on the form data
        $required_fields = array('email', 'password');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

        $fields_with_lengths = array('email' => 30, 'password' => 30);
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));

        $email = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['email']));
        $password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
        $hashed_password = md5($password);


        if ( empty($errors) ) {
            // Check database to see if email and the hashed password exist there.
            $query = "SELECT id, email, close_account ";
            $query .= "FROM ptb_users ";
            $query .= "WHERE email = '{$email}' ";
            $query .= "AND password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "AND close_account = '0' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($result_set);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
                // email/password authenticated
                // and only 1 match
                $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $found_user['email'];
                $_SESSION['sub_expires'] = $found_user['subscription_expires'];





                $result = mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET user_online='Online' WHERE id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error());

if($result) 
{ 
$_SESSION['login_message']="<div class=\"login-overlay\"></div><div class=\"login-box\"><div class=\"loginframe2\">
<h1>Login You In Securely </h1>
<p>login you in securely. Please wait.<br/><br/>
<div class=\"login-logo\">
  <img src=\"assets/css/photobox/loading.gif\" width=\"24\" height=\"24\"><div class=\"login-text-logo\">Login You In. Please Wait</div></div>
</div></div>"; 
header("Location:home.php");

}


            }else{

                // email/password combo was not found in the database
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\"><strong>Email / Password combination incorrect.</strong><br />
                    Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.</div>";
                    echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";

            }

                } else {
            if (count($errors) == 1) {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">There was 1 error in the form.<div>";


            } else {
                $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.<div>";
            }
        }


    } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">You are now logged out.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close3\"></div></a>";

    } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 2) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox_out\">Sorry, we've had to log you out. Your session has expired.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close2\"></div></a>";


            } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
            $message = "<div class=\"infobox\">You are now logged out.</div>";
            echo "<a href=\"#\"><div class=\"infobox-close3\"></div></a>";

        }

        } 

    }

        $email = "";
        $password = "";
    }
?>

<br/>
            <?php if (!empty($message)) {echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";} ?>
            <?php if (!empty($errors)) { display_errors($errors); } ?>

                     <? if (logged_in()) { ?> 

            <?php

$initial_prompt = initial_prompt();
while ($initial = mysql_fetch_array($initial_prompt)) 


 if ($initial['initial_prompt'] == '0')  {

 redirect_to("dashboard.php"); } ?>

 <? } ?>
```

Comment: put `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST,true).'</pre>';` on top of the PHP file and see if `$_POST['submit']` is set in Firefox. And let us know if you're submitting by clicking the image button or pressing enter key.

Comment: it just prints out this: Array
(
)

Comment: am trying the enter key and cliking the submit image button and neitehr works

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 0):

Missed this:

```
 <form id="myform" form action="login.php" method="post" class="loginform">
```

... should've been:

```
 <form id="myform" action="login.php" method="post" class="loginform">
```

And also, `value` in `type="image"` is off-specs. `type="image"` will only define the image as submit button.

Comment: ok ive fixed that but still noting. its going to login.php because it's coming up with the login error, wrong credentials, however the details are 100% correct when im trying to login, and it even comes up with firefoxes do you want firefox to remember password box. its just not physically login the user in.

Comment: Are you sure you put the `print_r()` line at the top of `login.php`? And it outputs an empty `array( )`?

Answer (score 0):

Browser handling for the submission of server side image maps (`<input type="image"`) is inconsistant.

All browsers should submit `name.x=x_coord` and `name.y=y_coord` (although when it hits the server, PHP will parse `.` as `_`) but not all will submit `name=Value`.

Don't test for `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` when `submit` is an image map.